# Can I use Java 7 with Vert.x any version?

Tags: java, vert.x

I need to use Vert.x as per requirement. Need to implement vert.x + Java 7

Just want to know can I implement Vert.X with Java 1.7, as Vert.X have lambda expression (i.e. not supported by Java 7). So is it compulsory Vert.X + Java 8 or Vert.X provided some alternative of Lambda Expression or lower version of Vert.X is Compatible with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vert.X in version 2. See http://vertx.io/vertx2/install.html for more Information

Comment: Thanks.. its really helpful

Answer (score -1):

No. [Vert.x applications require Java 8.](http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/)

Comment: This is only true for version 3. Version 2 supports Java 7.